# Connect tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, information-schema

In mySQL there are 2 tables `information_schema.tables` and `information_schema.innodb_tables`.

Latter contains table id for particular table for the innodb engine, but the engine itself contained inside the former.

Is there an easy way to connect 2 of them to get the table id of the given table? Or I will have to do 2 queries and get the engine first and then table id.

---

Maybe all I need is this:

```
SELECT st.table_id FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLES st  WHERE CONCAT(?,'/', ?) = st.name);
```

since there will be no record in the `innodb_tables` if the table was made with non-innodb engine, right? And therefore I will handle everything on the client side for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables t1 
JOIN information_schema.innodb_tables t2 
    ON CONCAT_WS('/', table_schema, table_name) = t2.name;
```

---

> This is correct, when you do not have partitioned tables. – Luuk

If there exists partitioned tables then

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables t1 
JOIN information_schema.innodb_tables t2 
    ON LOCATE(CONCAT_WS('/', table_schema, table_name), t2.name);
```

Comment: This is correct, when you do not have partitioned tables.

Comment: @Akina, please see my edit. So basically I'm saying that in my C++ code I will just assign the `id = 0` and if the query return no record - just exit. Otherwise I will assign returned id to that value.